# Computing limit by Hopital rule

Tags: calculus

How can I find the following limit by l'hospital rule?
$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \left(\frac{e^{x} - e^{-x}}{2}\right)^{\tan x}$$

Answer (score 1):

*With equivalents:*

The natural logarithm of the function is $\;\tan x\,\ln(\sinh x)$.

Now $\;\sinh x\sim_0 x$, hence $\;\ln(\sinh x)\sim_0\ln x$. Also $\tan x\sim_0 x$, hence
$$\tan x\,\ln(\sinh x)\sim_0 x\ln x \xrightarrow[x\to 0^+]{}0$$
so that
$$(\sinh x)^{\tan x}=\mathrm e^{\tan x\ln(\sinh x)}\xrightarrow[x\to 0^+]{}1.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \left(\frac{e^{x} - e^{-x}}{2}\right)^{\tan x}=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} exp(\tan x\ln|\frac{e^{x} - e^{-x}}{2}|)=exp(\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} \frac{\ln|\frac{e^{x} - e^{-x}}{2}|}{\cot x})$$